# insert values into a table if the value does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert values into a table where if the values does not exist then it should insert them but I am having issue with this SQL.

```
 insert into table1 (id, name, value)
    select Id, Name, Value
    from table2
    where NOT EXISTS typeId = TypeId;
```

Comment: It's not too hard to find examples of [how to use Exists](https://ittutorial.org/exists-and-not-exists-operator-in-oracle-sql-oracle-sql-tutorials-18/)

Answer (score 0):

Should've been something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, name, VALUE)
   SELECT id, name, VALUE
     FROM table2 b
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT NULL
                FROM table1 a
               WHERE a.typeid = b.typeid);
```

Comment: Hi, I still get the ORA-00001: unique constraint error.

Comment: Then TYPEID isn't (the only?) column that enforces uniqueness in that table. Please, post tables' description and primary keys, unique keys and unique indexes on that table.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a `MERGE` statement is good at:

```sql
MERGE INTO table1 dst
USING table2 src
ON (src.typeID = dst.typeID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, name, value) VALUES (src.Id, src.Name, src.Value);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (id PRIMARY KEY, typeid, name, value) AS
SELECT 2, 2, 't1-name2', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 't1-name4', 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (id PRIMARY KEY, typeid, name, value) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 't2-name1', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 't2-name2', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 't2-name3', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 't2-name4', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 5, 't2-name5', 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | TYPEID | NAME | VALUE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | 2 | t1-name2 | 2 |
> | 4 | 4 | t1-name4 | 4 |
> | 3 |  | t2-name3 | 3 |
> | 5 |  | t2-name5 | 5 |
> | 1 |  | t2-name1 | 1 |

*(Note: you probably want to include `TYPEID` in the columns you insert.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a7f9dd250b3993aa6740680e823e0def)*